# Visual Studio not picking up target local nuget feed location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, package

**Overview**

**Visual Studio 2015**

I have set up my own local nuget server as per Microsoft's instructions. I have it up and running and can get Visual Studio to pick it up. The only problem is that Visual Studio will only pick up my packages if it points to a local directory that I'd rather it didn't.

**Problem**

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds Microsoft advises that if you set up your own local nuget feed that this directory structure/file naming convention is best.

**$myserver\packages\packageID\version\packageID.version.nupkg**

I have followed this and currently have a directory structure/file like below

**C:\NugetServer\packages\MyCompany.MyProjectName\1.0.6498.30963\MyCompany.MyProjectName.1.0.6498.30963.nupkg**

I then point Visual Studio to **C:\NugetServer\packages** (ie I add my own local server as a nuget server with the **C:\NugetServer\packages** path)  and search for **MyCompany.MyProjectName** and get no results returned, **however** if I point it to

**C:\NugetServer\packages\MyCompany.MyProjectName** it will pick up the MyCompany.MyProjectName.1.0.6498.30963.nupkg

Obviously I don't want a structure like C:\NugetServer\packages\ where all my assemblies are dumped given there is potential for collisions between various assemblies sharing the same version. Anyone any ideas what I have done wrong here? How can I get Visual Studio to search my packages directory for packages?

Comment: Yes, using `nuget init` command, nuget will copy all the packages from a flat folder to a destination folder using a hierarchical layout . Since you have resolved this issue in your comment, would you please convert your comment to the answer, and mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a powershell script which was taking the result of nuget pack and then creating the directory structure with appropriate file name. I didn't need to do that given nuget init src destination completes that exact task. It also magically registered it with the feed and my problem was solved